# How to avoid Data Re-submit on Page Refresh on a OnePager Site + Avoid Browser PopUp

Tags: php, forms

i already searched a lot but none of these solutions can help me. I want to avoid Data Re-Submit on Page Refresh on a Onepager Site. I don´t got any other page to redirect. + Avoid Browser PopUp

I am a total beginner so sorry for the "terrible code".

```
<?php
$errors = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $issend = true;
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['phonenumber'])) {
        $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    }

    if ($phonenumber === null || mb_strlen($phonenumber) === 0) {
        $errors[] = 'phonenumber.empty';
    }

    if ($name === null || mb_strlen($name) === 0) {
        $errors[] = 'name.empty';
    }


    if (empty($errors)) {
        mail('email@email.com', 'Contact Form', 'Name: '.$_POST["name"] . '\n Telefonnummer:' .$_POST["phonenumber"]);
        $_POST['name'] = '' ;
        $_POST['phonenumber'] = '' ;
        $_POST = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on a successful submission, redirect the user to a success page. If you don't have one, just create a simple HTML/PHP page

*success.php*

```
<?php
    echo "Successful submission";
?>
```

Your page with the form add this to bottom of your check

```
if (empty($errors)) {
        mail('email@email.com', 'Contact Form', 'Name: '.$_POST["name"] . '\n 
        Telefonnummer:' .$_POST["phonenumber"]);
        $_POST['name'] = '' ;
        $_POST['phonenumber'] = '' ;
        $_POST = null;

        header('Location: http://www.domainname.com/success.php');
    }
```

Comment: if valid submit set a cookie or your own post flag, and you'd probably want to to use captcha for xss security, anti-spam-posting.

Comment: Cookies are not reliable for a form submit

Comment: Yes, that's true. A server side session variable could be though.